# Improving performance of LibraryLink evaluation

Tags: performance-tuning, librarylink

I have a large function that I want to integrate with an integration routine.
The function is supposed to be built out of LibraryLink functions, but I find evaluating the function to be very slow, and I am sure there must be a better way to program it, but I am new to this and can't see it.

The function is built out of some LibraryLink functions that take and return an array of length 2 (supposed to represent a complex number).

The situation: I have the LibraryLink function

`libFunc = LibraryFunctionLoad[lib,"libFunc",{{Real,1}},{Real,1}];`

and I want to evaluate

`largeExp = ...some function of...: myPlaceholder[{Re[1+n],Im[1+n]}]`.

Instead of the placeholder, I want to use `libFunc`. I use a placeholder because the argument contains a symbolic parameter `n`, so not directly a numerical list of length 2. Maybe this can be avoided, but how?

Then I declare

`func[n1_]:=largeExp /. n ->n1 /. myPlaceholder[x_]:> Complex@@libFunc[x]`

(in reality there are some 30 functions, each with its placeholder, so 30 replacement rules).
Then I integrate `func` by

`integrator[func,x]`

where `integrator[f_,x_]:=Module[{...}... where there are many evaluations of f/@someList...]`.

I find the performance of this solution to be slow: can anything be done about it?

I think that (maybe) the problem boils down to the fact that

```
func[0.5 + I] // Timing
Out[1]={0.000143, {-0.0572893229589844, 0.215877721621149}}
libFunc[{1.5, 1}] // Timing
Out[2]={0.000018, {-0.0572893229589844, 0.215877721621149}}
```

so there is some overhead somewhere, but how can I improve on my solution?

So in the end the code to improve looks like

```
libFunc = LibraryFunctionLoad[lib,"libFunc",{{Real,1}},{Real,1}];
largeExp = ...some function of...: myPlaceholder[{Re[1+n],Im[1+n]}]
func[n1_]:=largeExp /. n ->n1 /. myPlaceholder[x_]:> Complex@@libFunc[x]
integrator[func,x]
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Complex` type directly (instead of a Tensor of 2 Reals) for passing the argument and returning? See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithWolframLanguage.html#280210622

Comment: No... how would that work? Is there a quick example?

Comment: See the Mandelbrot Set example here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/Numerical.html it shows how to pass a complex number in Wolfram Language and get it in the C code.